# object cant inherit properties

Tags: object, inheritance

I get stack. PLZ help.

In class "work" i creating a frame of a table. Than in object "myWork1" i must fill that frame of a table.

But it didnt works. Finally i want to creating a table with special information in it.

What im doing wrong?

```
<p id="demo">demo</p>

function work(td1) {
this.firstWork = function(){
var table = document.createElement("table");
var table_tr = document.createElement("tr");
var table_td = document.createElement("td");
var table_td_text = document.createTextNode(this.td1=td1);
table_td.appendChild(table_td_text);
table_tr.appendChild(table_td);
table.appendChild(table_tr);
io.appendChild(table);  
}
}

var myWork1 = new work("111");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
return myWork1.tableWork();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p id="demo">demo</p>

function work(td1) {
    this.firstWork = function(){
         var table = document.createElement("table");
         var table_tr = document.createElement("tr");
         var table_td = document.createElement("td");
         var table_td_text = document.createTextNode(td1);
         table_td.appendChild(table_td_text);
         table_tr.appendChild(table_td);
         table.appendChild(table_tr);
         return table; 
    }
}

var myWork1 = new work("111");

document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(myWork1.firstWork());
```

A working example here : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfgumcc6/)